# Python, embed image (through a variable, not link) in telegram message

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Thanks in advance for any help.
Using this code:

```
bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, 
                 text ="[]([http://anylink.jpg]) some text",
                 parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2)
```

It works. 
But i wanted to load the link from and excel, to achieve something like this:

```
... 
img = (sheet2['A16'].value)
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, 
                     text ="[](img) some text",
                     parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2)
```

This last one doesn't work, it sends the message without any image.

Am i missing just the correct way to format?

edit: "img" comes from an excel: 1 column, first row a title, others a bunch of links like this:

> http://www.uplay.it/xthumb_7_Wonders.jpg.pagespeed.ic.IXPfh5y9em.jpg

```
file2 = load_workbook('images.xlsx') 
sheet2 = file2['Sheet1'] 
img = (sheet2['A16'].value)
```

Comment: Please show us the content of the `img` variable

Comment: thanks for the reply. edited

Comment: If you want a link thats redirect to the img try: `text="[" + img + "](Press me)",`. Aka: Link should be in the first `[]`

Comment: i had to modify in:
`text="[" + img + "\]\(Press me\)",''`
it thrown a:
`telegram.error.BadRequest: Can't parse entities: character '.' is reserved and must be escaped with the preceding '\'`

so i tried editing the link itself, in the excel document, like this:
`http://www\.uplay\.it/xthumb_Clans\.jpg\.pagespeed\.ic\.6RnOfuXWt3\.jpg`

and still it thrown a:
`telegram.error.BadRequest: Can't parse entities: can't find end of italic entity at byte offset 29`
which is the underscore.

Stucked now, but closer maybe!

Comment: `text="[{}](Press me)".format(img)`

Comment: Still: `telegram.error.BadRequest: Can't parse entities: character ']' is reserved and must be escaped with the preceding '\'`
And if formatted, again same error as before about `byte offest 29`

Comment: As far as i understand, Markdown can't support _ and * . Maybe i have to use HTML instead

Comment: Using HTML parse mode is easier, i did it. Switching to it!
Thanks anyway for the help!

Comment: Ahh, otherwise you should encode the URL, or maybe try MarkDown v1. Maybe you can answer your own question so other people may find it?

Comment: sure, i didnt because there is plenty of answers.
I'll try your ideas too, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I switched to HTML and using a different code because i find it easier, but still hoping for a reply!

`bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, 
                 text='Text here\n<a href="'+img+'">">&#8205;</a>', 
                 parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML)`

With this HTML telegram.bot will send the text + embedded image.
This way "img" can be either a link (.html) or an image link (.png).